# How to best handle SerializationException from KafkaConsumer poll method

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In a consumer poll loop in Kafka, when a SerializationException is thrown by the poll method, is there a way to just skip this message (aka a 'poison pill') and go on consuming the next event from the topic?

I could catch the exception and use the consumer.seek() method to move the offset to the next message, but that method requires the partition and the offset as input parameters. Is there a way to get those values?

I have example code in a github repos. To run the example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bjornhjelle/kafka-streams-examples-gradle.git
$ cd kafka-streams-examples-gradle
$ ./gradlew build -x test
$ ./gradlew test --tests no.test.SerializationExceptionExample
```

The example produces three events to Kafka. The second event causes the SerializationException. The exception is caught and logged. At this point I would like to move the offset past this event. Instead the thrown again in the poll loop. The third event is therefore not consumed, so the test fails.

I am aware of this open issue on the same topic, but it mentions Kafka client version < 0.10.0.1, while I use version 1.0.0:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4740

I am also aware that I could probably solve it by using Kafka Streams and the new functionality for handling poison pills there ([KIP-161: streams deserialization exception handlers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-161%3A+streams+deserialization+exception+handlers))

What caused me to look into this in the first place was this exception:
(the example code causes a different SerializationException since I was not able to re-create this one)

```
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3"         org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition apcitxpt-1 at offset 339798. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1
Caused by: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:500)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:135)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:77)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:119)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:93)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:65)
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedDeserializer$Wrapper.deserialize(ExtendedDeserializer.java:55)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:923)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$2600(Fetcher.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1100)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1200(Fetcher.java:949)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:570)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:531)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1170)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1103)
at no.ruter.nextgen.kafkaConsumerRunners.ApcInitRunner.run(ApcInitRunner.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you’re using consumer groups and catch the exception won’t the consumer just move on when you keep polling?

Comment: I use consumer groups, but I cannot see how that helps. A partition is assigned to only one consumer in the consumer group, so the bad message would still block the consumption of more messages from that partition, until I somehow am able to move the offset to after the current offset. If I let the process fail by not catching the exception, the partition would be re-assigned to another consumer in the group, and that consumer would then get the same problem with the bad message. (Correct me if I am wrong...)

Comment: > “until I somehow am able to move the offset”. If you catch the exception and the consumer doesn’t crash, it doesn’t keep reading and processing? With consumer groups, the consumer “moves the offset”. Doesn’t that happen if you catch, too?

Comment: No, if I catch the exception the offset is not committed since the exception came from the poll-method, so the message is not properly consumed. Same thing if I do not catch the exception, but let the application exit. The message stays ready to be consumed again until it expires because the retention period is reached. So until then all other consumption is 'blocked' on that partition.

Comment: I see. Sorry I’ve never had to deal with this. Yeah you should be able to seek/commit manually maybe? As you say in your question, that requires you to know the offset/partition, which you can keep track of as your consumer progresses. When you hit the exception, you’ll know the last message that was good.

Comment: I mean it’s easy to keep track of the partition/offset as they arrive by inspecting ProducerRecords. What I wonder is whether it’s ok to manually change offsets of a consumer in group mode. I’d look into that.

Comment: Yes, but a consumer may consume messages from more than one partition. When you consume a message you can store which partition/offset it has, but the next message may come from a different partition. The message provided by the exception has the partition/offset info, so if it could have get-methods to retrieve them they could be used as parameters to the seek-method to advance the offset. The message is for example : "Error deserializing key/value for partition songs-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption."  Thanks a lot for your comments, Dmitry!

Comment: You're welcome. (i) So yeah if you can get the topic/partition/offset either by keep track of offsets or the exception message, I wonder if you can commit the offset manually when the consumer is configured to commit automatically. (ii) https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/errors/SerializationException.html doesn't mention the consumer throwing this message. Which makes sense because the consumer performs de-serialization. (iii) Maybe the simplest thing is to change the serialization/deserialization logic.

Comment: I added the exception stack trace that caused me to look into this in the first place, it shows that the exception originates from KafkaConsumer.poll. I may re-write the application to use Kafka Streams so I can see if the new exception handler solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions I found are parsing the serialization exception message to get the required data. topic name, partition and offset:

```
catch (SerializationException se) {
                String s = se.getMessage().split("Error deserializing key/value for partition ")[1].split(". If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.")[0];
                String topic = s.split("-")[0];
                int offset = parseInt(s.split("offset ")[1]);
                int partition = parseInt(s.split("-")[1].split(" at")[0]);

                TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
                logger.debug("Skipping {}-{} offset {}", topic, partition , offset);
                consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset + 1L);}
```

Comment: This works but is not a solid approach because it depends on the actual message from the exception. So a better option is what you can see here: [link](https://jonboulineau.me/blog/kafka/dealing-with-bad-records-in-kafka) Capture the exception in the deserializer itself and then process the result accordingly in a consumerRecords loop.

Comment: Do not recommend doing this. It can be quite flaky e.g. if the topic name has "-" in it.